# swift2.0でのcsvの読み込み

Tags: swift

```
 @IBAction func readcsv(sender: AnyObject) {
    var result: [[String]] = []
    if let csvPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("location", ofType: "csv") {
        var csvString=""
        do{
            csvString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: csvPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
            textarea.text=textarea.text+csvString
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        csvString.enumerateLines { (line, stop) -> () in
            result.append(line.componentsSeparatedByString(","))

    }
        print(result)

    }
}
```

このコードのdoの中のNSStringの語尾のas!のところにwarningが出るんですがなぜでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ではないので、コメント欄に書きます。`textarea.text=textarea.text+csvString`は、`textarea.text += csvString`と短縮できます。

Comment: @Harawo `inout` パラメータでは `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` がアンラップされないため、アンラップする必要があります: `textarea.text! += csvString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSStringとStringはブリッジ関係になっていて、継承関係ではないので、「as」を使うということだと思います。「as?」と「as!」はダウンキャストを演算子です。